# Can I use a control handler (ctr+c) to forcefully break out of a function?

Tags: c++

In the sample code shown below, I have

```
BOOL WINAPI CtrlHandler(DWORD fdwCtrlType)
{
    switch (fdwCtrlType)
    {
        // Handle the CTRL-C signal. 
    case CTRL_C_EVENT:
        return TRUE;
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
}

int main()
{
    /* some initializations */
    while(true)
    {
        process_user_input();
    }
}

process_user_input(...)
{
    /* checks input from a bunch of user inputs*/
    execute_xxx();
}

execute_xxx()
{
    /* do something */
    /* checks for a flag*/
    while(!flag)
    {
         /* do something*/
    }
}
```

in the execute_xxx() function, let's say that the app stopped there and is waiting for a flag, is there a way to clear the resources that were used and just go back to the while loop in the main function using ctrl+c?

Comment: What does the flag do/ waiting for? You can achieve this through CTRL+C handler, but there might be better ways to achieve this.

Comment: This cannot be done in a platform neutral way. If you are asking about Windows, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62186509/edit) the question and add the `winapi` tag (also refer to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/registering-a-control-handler-function) for what the return value means for a `CTRL_C_EVENT`).

Comment: If your resources follow the standard C++ RAII paradigm, you could get `execute_xxx` to throw an exception when it detects the flag is set.  The `main` function can wrap the call in a try-catch block.  Properly encapsulated resources will be released as the stack unwinds in response to the exception.

Comment: If you want to interrupt a wait, it might be prudent to show how you are waiting. Is it just that loop iterating over and over again? (That's not something I would call "waiting" as it is doing something.)